Comparing two generalized linear models with same predictors but different datasets
I want to know if the coefficients are different between two or more groups (e.g. elder vs. young, daytime vs. nighttime accidents). I heard about the Chow test, but it only works for linear regression. I want to apply this to Poisson or logistic regressions. I read some papers (like this one) that use the likelihood ratio test for this matter, but I'm not sure how it works.

Do you have the data or only some glm output?

@Glen_b Yes, I have the data.

Just to confirm, as it says in the title of your question, are you testing whether coefficients are different across two different data sets or simply whether a linear relationship (or other regression coefficient) varies by group in the same overall dataset? The best answer to your question depends on clarity around this issue.

@RickHass I'm looking for evidence to show whether the data should be modeled separately or not.

This is kind of a straightforward "chunk" test.
For a simple model, fit the regression without any regard for group.
In a more complicated model, interact the group variable with every variable in the model, as well as leaving it in alone without any interaction.
Test the complicated model, with the null hypothesis being that the coefficients on the features involving the group variable are zero (all of them).
Below, I give an example in R software, using a logistic regression.
library(lmtest)
set.seed(2024)

# Size of group 0
#
N0 <- 100

# Size of group 1
#
N1 <- 90

# Total size
#
N <- N0 + N1

# Simulate two covariates
# If you have more or they are correlated, so be it
#
x1 <- runif(N, 0, 1)
x2 <- runif(N, 0, 1)

# Define the group variable
#
g <- c(
  rep(0, N0),
  rep(1, N1)
)

# Simulate the binary outcome
#
z <- (1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 - 7*g + g*x1)/4 # linear combination with a bias
pr <- 1/(1+exp(-z))                   # pass through an inv-logit function
y <- rbinom(N, 1, pr)                 # Bernoulli response variable
 
# Fit a simple model with just the covariates
#
L0 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# Fit a complicated model that interacts the group variable with the covariates
#
L1 <- glm(y ~ g*(x1 + x2), family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# Run a hypothesis test, this being a likelihood-ratio chi-squared test
#
lmtest::lrtest(L0, L1) # I get a low p-value of 0.001446, consistent with the
                       # simulated data where the coefficients on the features
                       # using the group variable are not all zero

When you do this with a Wald test, lmtest::waldtest in R, of nested OLS linear models, that is the same as running the Chow test (this comes from old lecture notes from a class that used Wooldridge's "Introductory Econometrics" 6th edition, chapter 7), so this can be regarded as a generalization of the Chow test to a GLM setting. Wald tests, however, present some problems for nested logistic regressions, so I am using a likelihood-ratio test.
You can read about likelihood ratio tests of nested GLMs in Agresti (2015). I also recommend the link at the beginning of this answer about "chunk" tests.
This can be extended to the case where there are multiple groups, not just two.
library(lmtest)
set.seed(2024)

# Size of group 0
#
N0 <- 100

# Size of group 1
#
N1 <- 90

# Size of group 2
#
N2 <- 55

# Size of group 3
#
N3 <- 67

# Total size
#
N <- N0 + N1 + N2 + N3

# Simulate two covariates
# If you have more or they are correlated, so be it
#
x1 <- runif(N, 0, 1)
x2 <- runif(N, 0, 1)

# Define the group variable
#
g <- as.factor(c(
  rep(0, N0),
  rep(1, N1),
  rep(2, N2),
  rep(3, N3)
))

# Simulate the binary outcome
#
z <- 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2  # linear combination with a bias
pr <- 1/(1+exp(-z))   # pass through an inv-logit function
y <- rbinom(N, 1, pr) # Bernoulli response variable


# Fit a simple model with just the covariates
#
L0 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# Fit a complicated model that interacts the group variable with the covariates
#
L1 <- glm(y ~ g*(x1 + x2), family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# Run a hypothesis test, this being a likelihood-ratio chi-squared test
#
lmtest::lrtest(L0, L1) # I get a high p-value of 0.1122, consistent with the
                       # simulated data where the coefficients on the features
                       # using the group variable are zero.
                       # Indeed, such features are explicitly omitted, leaving
                       # implicit their coefficients of zero

# Check out the summary of L1 to see what, explicitly, all of the interaction
# features are
#
summary(L1)

(To understand this, I would consider it required background knowledge to know how ANOVA is encoded as a regression.)
Here is a simulation where I explicitly work with each group to set their coefficient values.
library(lmtest)
set.seed(2024)

# Size of group 0
#
N0 <- 100

# Size of group 1
#
N1 <- 90

# Size of group 2
#
N2 <- 55

# Size of group 3
#
N3 <- 67

# Total size
#
N <- N0 + N1 + N2 + N3

# Simulate two covariates
# If you have more or they are correlated, so be it
#
x1 <- runif(N, 0, 1)
x2 <- runif(N, 0, 1)

# Define the group variable
#
g <- as.factor(c(
  rep(0, N0),
  rep(1, N1),
  rep(2, N2),
  rep(3, N3)
))

# Simulate the binary outcome
#
# Simulate the linear combination with a bias for each group
#
z0 <- -1 + 2*x1[g == 0] + 3*x2[g == 0]
z1 <- -1 + 2*x1[g == 1] + 3*x2[g == 1]
z2 <- -1 + 2*x1[g == 2] + 3*x2[g == 2]
z3 <- -1 + 3*x1[g == 3] + 6*x2[g == 3]
z <- c(z0, z1, z2, z3)
#
pr <- 1/(1+exp(-z))   # pass through an inv-logit function
y <- rbinom(N, 1, pr) # Bernoulli response variable

# Fit a simple model with just the covariates
#
L0 <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# Fit a complicated model that interacts the group variable with the covariates
#
L1 <- glm(y ~ g*(x1 + x2), family = binomial(link = "logit"))

# Run a hypothesis test, this being a likelihood-ratio chi-squared test
#
lmtest::lrtest(L0, L1) # I get a low p-value of 0.02649, consistent with the
                       # simulated data where the coefficients are not the 
                       # same for all four models. Three groups have the same
                       # values, but the fourth group differs

REFERENCES
Agresti, Alan. Foundations of linear and generalized linear models. John Wiley & Sons, 2015.
Wooldridge, Jeffrey. Introductory econometrics: A modern approach. Cengage Learning, 2015.

Thank you! So if there are three groups then I have to develop three complicated models (each with one group variable) and run the test three times (L0 vs L1, L0 vs L2, L1 vs L2)? Is that right?

You can put $3+$ groups in one equation. I have given an example.
